# How to detect if browser supports multiple text-shadows?

Tags: browser-detection, css

I am having trouble detecting for CSS **multiple** text-shadows browser support:

```
text-shadow:0 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
```

For single value there is no problem and Modernizr works well there.
I have very specific shadow effect, and when I use it with some android ver2 devices, their browsers render text invisible. Text IS invisible without shadow and only shadows give text contours. So, I want to detect in JS and manage with class this problem.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Problem is now more difficult then I tought. Android v2 browsers have problems with last parameter of text-shadow - blur amount. If this is 0, your text-shadow is gone! So,
`text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 0 0 #D67424` will not render at all on android v2 browsers! But `text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 0 1px #D67424` is okay (but blurry for my needs:) )

Comment: You mean that you don't have any base-color?(`color`)

Comment: Yes. Text is transparent.

Comment: Hmm, i can't reproduce this. However i did see some similar problems where the browser needed a color property. What if you set `color: transparent;`?

Comment: How about try the other side - detect if there is no support for text transparency?

Comment: Yes, color is literally set > color:transparent;
But, same would be with color:white;
Problem is with android browser - it does not want to render shadows.

Comment: It's still a significant-ish chunk, but Android 2.x only represents 1/4 of Android browsers nowdays - it's on its way out. http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Great news! Of course, I still need to make it work on these devices...